# CVE-2021-26855 Explanation

Tags: exchange, cve

I patched on 3/3

This just looks like we were probed and not compromised, can some one please confirm? I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Ran Test-Hafnium.ps1

Contents of CVE-2021-26855.log

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"DateTime","AnchorMailbox"
"2021-03-02T09:50:56.279Z","ServerInfo~a]@Exchange001.contoso.com:444/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml?#"
```

edit:
The scan found the following entry

```
2021-03-02T09:50:56.279Z,5f083d36-1b8a-489b-9bdc-e3859dea08f4,15,1,2106,2,,Ecp,207.207.49.16,/ecp/y.js,,FBA,false,,,ServerInfo~a]@Exchange001.contoso.com:444/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml?#,ExchangeServicesClient/0.0.0.0,157.230.221.198,EXCHANGE001,200,200,,POST,Proxy,exchange001.contoso.com,15.00.0001.000,IntraForest,X-BEResource-Cookie,,,,347,362,,,0,0,,0,,0,,0,0,,0,295,0,0,17,0,274,0,0,0,1,0,294,1,274,4,21,21,295,,,,BeginRequest=2021-03-02T09:50:55.983Z;CorrelationID=<empty>;ProxyState-Run=None;FEAuth=BEVersion-1941962753;NewConnection=::1&0;BeginGetRequestStream=2021-03-02T09:50:55.983Z;OnRequestStreamReady=2021-03-02T09:50:55.998Z;BeginGetResponse=2021-03-02T09:50:55.998Z;OnResponseReady=2021-03-02T09:50:56.279Z;EndGetResponse=2021-03-02T09:50:56.279Z;ProxyState-Complete=ProxyResponseData;SharedCacheGuard=0;EndRequest=2021-03-02T09:50:56.279Z;,,,,,,CafeV1
```

In the following file

```
"\\exchange001.contoso.com\C$\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Logging\HttpProxy\Ecp\HttpProxy_2021030209-1.LOG"
```

I did not find any entries for Administrator@domain.com in any of the log files

Comment: Please add more detail to assist us in answering.

Comment: edited original post @DaveM

Comment: In the case of CVE-2021-26855 exploit, the `AuthenticatedUser` is empty, so you won't find any Administrator entries. You should look around for web shells and archives indicating data extraction, as described in the [Microsoft security blog post](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2021/03/02/hafnium-targeting-exchange-servers/)

Comment: Make sure you have updated your Exchange server to the latest version and applied the security patch.

Follow the steps introduced in the above link especially the part Can I determine if I have been compromised by this activity?

And also refer to the FAQ about this issue here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/298536/faq-for-march-2021-exchange-server-security-update.html

Answer (score 0):

You should review the logs attached to the service accessed - in this instance, the autodiscover logs in the %PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Logging directory.

More details about what to look for from an attack are available here:

https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2021/03/02/hafnium-targeting-exchange-servers/

Under "Attack details".